# Can I get the result in JSON format from MySQL database

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, node.js

I working with Nodejs and MySQL. I want the data which is returned by the MySQL database in the JSON format. Can someone guide me how to do that.

Comment: encode your result in json using `json_encode($result)`

Comment: I don't see a php tag there

Comment: can we do without using the php?

Comment: @BlueSuiter question is tagged with NodeJS not PHP..

Comment: @phoneix thank you for correcting me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following line to return all the returned rows in json:

```
res.json({"error" : false, "Messages" : rows});
```

> res.json eventually calls res.send

but before that it:

- respects the json spaces and json replacer app settings
- ensures the response will have utf8 charset and application/json
  content-type

P.S: As per your need, you want it in a variable so this should work for you:

```
    var result = [];
    for (var name in array) {
      if (array.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        result.push({name: name, array: array[name]});
      }
    }
    JSON.stringify(result) // use it to store in any variable.
```

You can use result anywhere then. This is a dummy example.

Comment: thank you. but i need to store the data in the variable no need to display in on the UI.

Comment: I'm getting the data from the database so the all data will be in the single variable "rows". you are providing code for a normal array if I'm not wrong.

Comment: That should be an array not a single string. Try to print that and check this then.